# How to input two values into one field using implode

Tags: php

```
<?php include 'connection.php'; ?>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    $description1 = $_REQUEST['description1'];
    $a = $description1;
    $description2 = $_REQUEST['description2'];
    $b = $description2;
    $f = array('$a', '$b');
    $g = implode(" ", $f);
    echo $g;
    $qr = mysql_query("insert into module1 values('','$g')");
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="cform"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="description1[]" /><br />
            <input type="text" name="description2[]" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
```

I want to insert the value of description1 & description2 into one feild of a table of database.. How to do that?

Comment: What is the current result?

Answer (score 4):

Use `json_encode()`

```
$f = json_encode(array('$a', '$b'));
```

Retrieve it using `json_decode()`

Answer (score 3):

First of all you're sending arrays `name="description1[]"` so need to use `$_REQUEST['description1'][0]`

Awful lot of code just to do this

```
$g = $_REQUEST['description1'][0] . ' ' . $_REQUEST['description2'][0];
```

but since you asked specifically to use implode

```
$g = implode(' ', array($_REQUEST['description1'][0], $_REQUEST['description2'][0]));
```

Comment: Implode is doing the same thing

Comment: Yes asim, after setting 5 other variables for no reason

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to merge your array

```
$f = array_merge($a, $b);
$g = implode(" ", $f);
echo $g;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the way you named the fields. The square brackets make them arrays and so you would need to access $_REQUEST['description1'][0] instead.

Try this code, I cleaned it a little but kept it the same direction you were heading.

```
<?php include 'connection.php';?>

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $arrayDescription = array(
        $_REQUEST['description1'],
        $_REQUEST['description2']
    );
    $stringDescription = implode(' ', $arrayDescription);
    echo $stringDescription
    $qr = mysql_query("insert into module1 values('','$stringDescription')");
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="cform"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="description1" /><br />
            <input type="text" name="description2" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML why are you using array notation in `description1[]` and `description2[]` variables where as these two variables are totally different by name. Use `description1` and `description2` in names and on PHP side get values through `$_POST['description1']` and `$_POST['description2']`. Rest of your code is correct.